# CSS - trying to keep the links inside the top nav on browser resize

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the "item" links inside the "menu" to stay inside the "navWrapper"/"navContent" when the browser is resized.....yet when I decrease the width of the browser window they keep staying off to the right outside these divs....any ideas on how to keep them all contained inside the nav area?

```
<div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="navContent">
    <div id="logo"><img src="assets/logo.png"></div>
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a></div>
    </div>
</div>


#navWrapper {
    background-color:#3f3f3f;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
   margin-top:0 auto;
}

#navContent {
   width:950px;
   height:65px;
}

#navContent #logo {
   width:200px;
   float:left;
   display:inline;
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top:15px;
}

#navContent #menu {
   width:466px;
   height:25px;
   float:right;
   display:inline;
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   margin-right:30px;
   margin-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use percentages. The reason that is happening is because you have a set `width` on `#navContent #menu`. That `div` will always be `466px`.

Comment: check the answer and tell if you want this ??

Comment: @disinfor - perfect, yep percentages....ahhhh, that does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/7XFsH/

HTML

```
<div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="navContent">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="assets/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <!-- #logo -->
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- #navContent -->
</div>
<!-- #navWrapper -->
```

CSS

```
#navWrapper {
    background-color:#3f3f3f;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    margin-top:0 auto;
}
#navContent {
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
}
#navContent #logo {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#navContent #menu {
    height:25px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.item a {
    color:white;
}
```

It also makes the `navContent` responsive.

Comment: Love that this turns to a responsive nav...thank you for that tip!

Comment: very nice  nice thing about SO you get to learn from all Free

Comment: No problem. You'll have to adjust the `logo` size to use percentages as well (because it's always at `200px`, but that's the start for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you keep the menu with a fixed width that is going to happen always.

I suggest you to dig into mediaqueries so, depeding on the screen resolution, are the styles you might set.

Also you can try by setting the navContent like this:

```
#navContent {max-width:950px;} /* instead of width */
```

And remove the width in the #menu, is not required if is floated.

This way the nav is not going to be wider than its containers (be sure there are no containers with a fixed with).

I insist, if you want to be very accurate on the result, try by appliying mediaqueries.

Here some [documentation](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and a cool tool to detect what resolution you are viewing [[link](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html)]

Answer (score 0):

**This method is only recommended if your header does not have an expanding height  (ie, if the navigation isn't *supposed* to wrap**

Give the container a min/max width, but let it use "auto" as the actual width. The minimum will allow users on small screens/devices to scroll over and use your navigation, rather than letting it spill off screen and potentially out of the box. It still goes off-screen, but in an expected way. (tip: use an @media query to change the menu layout on those small screens)

```
#navWrapper {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 560px;
}
```

Position the #navContent so that it is relative and does not have a width. This will let you position children elements relative to this div. Note that you must specify a height for this container as well, but you have already done that in your CSS

```
#navContent {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

Now position the elements that should appear in the menu. Don't bother with margin or padding for the original elements. Use absolute positioning. Get it perfect.

The magic, you can attach this to the right of the menu.

```
#navContent #logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30px;

    /* Used to reset your CSS */
    margin: 0; 
}
#navContent #menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;

    /* Used to reset your CSS */
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

For the navigation, I suggest the .item classes be inline, and the links be floated blocks. This means the "items" won't be much more than a wrapper, and the links can be given a background or borders without the strange "deadzone" between them. Padding on navigation links is great for usability & touch devices.

```
#navContent #menu .item {
    display: inline;
}
#navContent #menu .item a {
    display: block;
    float: left;

    /* padding, background, border... go nuts */
}
```

You don't need to clear the navigation in this case, since the #menu is positioned absolutely it won't affect other elements to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

try this

html

```
<div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="navContent">
    <div id="logo"><img src="assets/doityourweb-logo.png"/></div></div>
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="">dadada</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#navWrapper {
    background-color:#3f3f3f;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
   margin-top:0 auto;
}

#navContent {
   width:950px;
   height:65px;
}

#navContent #logo {
   width:200px;
   float:left;
   display:inline;
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top:15px;
}

#navContent #menu {
   width:466px;
   height:25px;
   float:left;
   padding-left:8%;     
   display:inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   margin-right:50px;
   margin-top:15px;
}
.item{
    display:inline-block;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6B8x/

P.S i dont know where you want to close your #navContent so check and tell

Comment: The HTML is wrong (it was in the initial post as well). There isn't a closing tag on the the `img` and `navContent` isn't closed either.

Comment: The links still fall out of the nav though :/